# Странное изменение массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach, конструктор

```
function makeTest() {

  var arr = [5,4,3,2,1];
  console.log(arr);

  arr.forEach(function(elem,index) {
    arr[index] = 2;
  })
}

var test = new makeTest();
```

При запуске этого кода, в консоль выводится: [image: Консоль]
Объясните, пожалуйста, почему массив изменяется до запуска forEach и почему в консоли он выглядит как [5,4,3,2,1], а все его элементы в то же время равны 2 (Или я чего то не понимаю).

Comment: Особенность работы консоли.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`

Comment: в свернутом виде показывается массив на момент вывода в консоль, в развернутом показывается массив на момент разворачивания, то есть уже измененный

Comment: Спасибо, я понял выше сказанное, но объясните, пожалуйста, почему он выводится уже измененный, если foreach стоит после console.log?

Comment: @Borod, ситуация не имеет отношения к коду, с ним все ок - это хромиум так пытается улучшить наше качество жизни. Наведи курсор на синий значок `i` в строке вывода, посмотри что там написано.